# slot machine style numbers jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to achieve a slot machine style rolling numbers in my website, but I need to be able to preset what the final numbers will be when the slots stop spinning, and I could really use some clear example to start from or even a working example I can manipulate.  Would anyone have the time to show me how this could be done?  As a reference to what I'm looking for, I've been trying to get the slot machine plugin located here: https://github.com/matthewlein/jQuery-jSlots  to work for what I need, but I am not able to find a way of setting what the numbers should each land on, can only get standard random results.

Comment: If I am understanding your question, I think simply having a div containing your elements that you want to display, and then positioning that div vertically within another div where the outer div has overflow hidden should work.

Comment: what I'm trying to do is use code at the above link, but modify it so I can set which numbers will come up for a standard 3 column slot machine.  Right now it returns random numbers, but I want to make it so i can give it like 5,3,10 for example, and have those numbers show after it's done spinning, have them be the final result.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the `finish` function on line 160 to use your numbers instead of the random ones. You will also need to communicate with the `jSlots` object to tell it what numbers to use.

Comment: thank you Fallexe for your response, I figured it out and have it working as I need it to.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to modify the plugin code slightly. This is not a complete solution but here is something to get you started. Change the `playSlots` function to accept an array of numbers, which will be your desired final numbers.

```
base.playSlots = function(values) {

    base.values = values;

    ...etc
}
```

You'd call it like:

```
playSlots([7, 7, 7]);
```

The slots will need to know which position in the array they correspond to, so you'll have to modify the setup a bit. In the setup function, you should pass the index to the Slot() object when instantiating.

```
for (var i = base.options.number - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    base.allSlots.push( new base.Slot(i) );
}
```

And in the slot constructor, you should store a reference to it.

```
base.Slot = function(slotIndex) {

    this.slotIndex = slotIndex;

    etc...
};
```

Finally, in the finish method, which is called on the last rotation, replace the random number generation with your pre-selected numbers.

```
finish : function() {

    ...etc

    var endNum = base.values[this.slotIndex];

    ..etc
}
```

Comment: This answer is great and works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is:

```
<div id="spinner"></div>
```

look for the body tag and add onto the tag: onLoad="setbg()"

Ad then the js code

```
function roll() {
    var spinners = new Array;
    spinners[0] = spin(0);
    spinners[1] = spin(1);
    spinners[2] = spin(2);
    spinners[3] = spin(3);
    spinners[4] = spin(4);
    spinners[5] = spin(5);
    spinners[6] = spin(6);
    spinners[7] = spin(7);
    spinners[8] = spin(8);
    spinners[9] = spin(9);
    spinners[10] = spin(10);
    spinners[11] = spin(11);

    document.getElementById('spinner').innerHTML = '<img src="rolling.png"> math.floor(math.random()*spinners.length);
} 
function spin(spinnumber) {
    if (spinnumber == 0) {
        document.getElementById('spinner').innerHTML = '<img src="spinimage0.png" />';
    } else if (spinnumber == 1) {
        document.getElementById('spinner').innerHTML = '<img src="spinimage1.png" />';
    } else if (spinnumber == 2) {
        document.getElementById('spinner').innerHTML = '<img src="spinimage2.png" />';
    } else if (spinnumber == 3) {
        document.getElementById('spinner').innerHTML = '<img src="spinimage3.png" />';
    else if (spinnumber == 4) {
        document.getElementById('spinner').innerHTML = '<img src="spinimage4.png" />';
    } else if (spinnumber == 5) {
        document.getElementById('spinner').innerHTML = '<img src="spinimage5.png" />';
    } else if (spinnumber == 6) {
        document.getElementById('spinner').innerHTML = '<img src="spinimage6.png" />';
    } else if (spinnumber == 7) {
        document.getElementById('spinner').innerHTML = '<img src="spinimage7.png" />';
    } else if (spinnumber == 8) {
        document.getElementById('spinner').innerHTML = '<img src="spinimage8.png" />';
    } else if (spinnumber == 9) {
        document.getElementById('spinner').innerHTML = '<img src="spinimage9.png" />';
    } else if (spinnumber == 10) {
        document.getElementById('spinner').innerHTML = '<img src="spinimage10.png" />';
    } else if (spinnumber == 10) {
        document.getElementById('spinner').innerHTML = '<img src="spinimage10.png" />';
    } else if (spinnumber == 11) {
        document.getElementById('spinner').innerHTML = '<img src="spinimage11.png" />';
    }
}
function setbg({
    document.getElementById('spinner').innerHTML = '<img src="spinnerbg.png">'
};
```

Note you'll need images called spinnerbg.png, spinimage0-11.png, rolling.png and that's all!